# Wget command "Post" with --no-check-certificate failed :Certificate common name doesnt match

Tags: python, wget

I'm running on Windows>Visual Studio>Python and using WGET in my code.

I'm trying to call API (Post).

This is the code:

```
APIWGET = [WGETInstallationFolder,'--no-check-certificate',"--post-data="% PostFile,"--output-file="+TempReadWritePath + 'TempReadWriteFile' + TimeNow + '.txt',"--wait=2","--content-on-error","--header="+Header, "--output-document="+TempReadWritePath + 'TempReadWriteFile' + TimeNow + '.txt',"--timeout=3","--tries=3", "--save-headers", "https://" +APIGWIP +"xxxxxxxx/"]  

call(APIWGET)
```

And getting certificate common name doesn't match..

Mention that when I call the same API with "GET" everything works ok.

Comment: Well, for one thing `"--post-data="% PostFile` doesn't look right.

Comment: Yep you are right, i removed the % postfile and instead %s just set somting to post and it works.I'll find another way to pass value to this flag.Thanks a lot